# Is a 'title' attribute relevant in a <img> tag?

Tags: html, image, semantics

I wanted to know if adding a **'title'** attribute is semantic relevant on a **'img'** tag. I already always use the **'alt'** attribute to respec the W3C spec.
And if yes, is the content on the 'title' attribute have to be different from the 'alt' one ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517484/html-title-attribute-any-limitation-on-which-tag-to-apply-it-on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `title` attribute can be used as semantic, i.e. as relating to meaning. As such, it is defined to be an advisory title, and browsers may make its value optionally available to users, e.g. as a tooltip on mouseover or as a cue spoken by a speech browser. This means that it can be used for a multitude of purposes, semantic or other. It is up to you to decide whether you use it to describe the meaning of the image, or to give authorship information, or e.g. just to show a name for the image (the name may or may not describe the meaning).

Search engines may treat the `title` text as relating to the image, possibly causing a page to appear in image searches when words appearing in that text are used. The details of such processing have not been disclosed and probably vary from one search engine to another.

There is no reason why the value of the `title` attribute should not be the same as the value of the `alt` attribute. They have different purposes, but sometimes the same text can serve both. For example, if the image contains a person’s signature, the `alt` attribute should probably contain just the name in the signature, and the `title` attribute could contain the same (e.g., to help people who can see the image but cannot read the name easily), or it could be more explanatory, e.g. `title="Joe Q. Public (signature)"`.

Comment: Thank you for this very well explained answer !

Comment: `"The details of such processing have not been disclosed and probably vary from one search engine to another"` that's why I suspect most SEO so-called specialists mostly have no clue what they are talking about. Unless hardcore experimentation & analysis, there no way you can check your knowledge, nor prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a little about what @SLaks said in their answer. The `title` attribute can also help with SEO and expressing more about what a web page has to offer. Just a tid bit to add is all.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute can be used to add a tooltip to any HTML element, including `<img>`.

It can be, but does not need to be, the same as the `alt` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I already know that, my question aim the Semantic interest of using this attribute. But thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

its relevant. alt attribute is for useragents which not display images, in this case it will show the alt attribute. alt attribute is required for a responsive webdesign (WCAG). title attribute are optional for tooltips and this must be not the same as alt.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearly explaining the difference between the two attributes. But is using the 'title' attr is good for SEO or is it only useful for tooltips ?

Comment: its good for accessibillity. therefore its good for SEO, too.

Comment: The `title` attribute is not only for tooltips. There is no reason why its value should not be the same as the value of the `alt` attribute; they have different purposes, but sometime the same text can serve both. And by “responsive webdesign” you probably meant accessibility, a very different issue.

Comment: responsive is webdesign for all end-devices. this belongs to accessibility, too (but you are right, its a different issue). Title attrributes is a helper attribute for a device, which gives an element a title. Alt-Attribute is a fallback attribute for non displaying.