# HTML "title" attribute: any limitation on which tag to apply it on?

Tags: html

I have read [on Mozilla website regarding the `title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#title) : `"contains a text representing advisory information related to the element it belongs to"`.

But also, in the first paragraph of the page regarding all global attributes (`title` included): "`HTML defines a few attributes that are common to all HTML elements. These attributes can be used on all elements, though the attributes may have no effect on some elements"`

Is it anywhere specified (source please) on which element the `title` attribute has "no effect"?

I curious why this seems so vague, maybe I simply missed something.

[I created a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2x9x/) where `title` attribute seems to "have an effect" (on Chrome, FF29, IE11) on tags: `<a>`, `<img>`, `<p>`, `<div>`

Comment: Read the docs for each tag. They tell you what attributes are valid for it. What the browsers choose with the (in)valid HTML you provide is up to them and will differ and not necessarily follow standards.

Comment: In HTML5 isn't it valid in all tags?

Comment: @JohnConde Alright, that's interesting. So if I'd like to apply it on a label & check that it is actually is used by all the browsers I want to support in my web app, I'll need to go on each relevant browser doc & make sure it behaves as expected? seems like this attribute was first provided for SEO purpose & eventually used by "some" browsers to display this "potentially additional" info to the user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on HTML version where the `title` attribute is valid. Originally, it was allowed for links (`a` elements) only and was meant to help the user see, on mouseover, some information about the linked resource, useful for deciding whether to follow the link or not. This might still be regarded as the most useful way of using `title`.

Later, the attribute was allowed for most elements, and HTML5 proposes to remove all restrictions, mainly just for simplicity. The formulation about the effects is intentionally vague, since the effects are expected to be browser-dependent, and they often are. For example, speech-based browsers may optionally speak the `title` attribute value when encountering an element that has it; but this can usually be switched off.

For example, in HTML5, the `title` attribute is also allowed for a `head` element, but it normally has no effect there, since that has no content to be rendered (as part of the document).

The `title` attribute is mostly used to show users information (“tooltip”) on mouseover. This is in many ways problematic, due to the primitive and uncontrollable user interface and other problems. Therefore, people often use other techniques, such as “CSS tooltips”, instead. But for compatibility with past specifications and practices, `title` attributes are kept as part of the language. It is unlikely that its meaning will be specified more exactly.

Comment: `"the effects are expected to be browser-dependent, and they often are."`: exactly what no one wants, a browser dependent implementation. Regarding the SEO-or-not usage, most people say no, some yes, it's SEO you know... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1005/36097